# Linux/Gnome mouse bluetooth lost Natural Scrolling configuration after reboot/resume

Tags: gnome, bluetooth

I have a Logitec Master MX 2 mouse (Bluetooth) connected to a Manjaro Linux, and I'm using the Natural Scrolling configuration. But if I reboot or resume the system the scrolling back to the normal mode (not natural Scrolling). I have another Linux system running POP_OS (Gnome) and have the same problem.

I need to open de Settings > Mouse & Stouchpad > Disable and enable again the function to have back the natural scrolling.

I know this is a minor problem but has a huge impact on productivity for me. I was thinking maybe a script to "disable > enable" de natural mouse could help me.

Anyone have some kind of bluetooth problem like this?

My primary system:

DISTRIB_RELEASE = 20.2

GNOME version = 3.381

Linux = 5.8.18-1

Thanks!

Comment: This was probably fixed by this PR: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1553

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue with a Logitech M325 mouse.  This is NOT a Bluetooth mouse; it uses the Logitech Unifying Receiver.

So I don't think it's a Bluetooth-related issue, but more likely something to do with GNOME and its underlying architecture for storing and applying hardware configuration settings.

Interestingly, this issue doesn't affect the touchpad on the same laptop.  Possibly that's because the touchpad is always attached whereas the mouse is attached only when the laptop is docked (the Unifying Receiver is plugged into a USB port on the dock).

FWIW, KDE has a history of similar problems.  I never saw this on GNOME until upgrading from Fedora 32 to 33 (and upgrading GNOME to 3.38.1).

Incidentally, you can toggle the setting in a terminal or a script with these commands:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information, and the command line, it works great. The touchpad works normally, as you mentioned.
Bye!

Comment: The issue seems to have disappeared on my system.  I assume something got fixed in a package update.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported the bug here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3421

I also [found a workaround](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/mouse-natural-scrolling-setting-not-persisting-after-update/36952):

> Inside `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` add this line:
>
> ```
> Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
> ```
>
> right above the line Driver "libinput"
>
> Reboot and test again.